# What is the proper way to set up a jsbindings class with cocos2d-js?

Tags: javascript, c++, cmake, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-js

The [documentation](https://github.com/cocos2d/bindings-generator) explains how to generates jsbindings, but it does not tell the proper way to integrate it into a project. What steps do I must follow? Where should I store my manually written C++ files? Where should I store the generated js and c++ files? What CMakeList.txt files should I edit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found some way to do this.
Please confirm me I don't do anything wrong (I copied this message on the [official forum](http://discuss.cocos2d-x.org/t/what-is-the-proper-way-to-set-up-a-jsbindings-class-with-cocos2d-js/18119)).

Let's integrate the js-bindings test samples in a cocos2d-js project.

- First generate the tests : `cd tools/bindings-generator/test && ./test.sh  && cd ../../..` (that may need some configuration). At the moment it fails on Linux because of missing headers but I submited a [merge request](https://github.com/cocos2d/bindings-generator/pull/141).
- Copy files into the project 
  `cp -R tools/bindings-generator/test/simple_test/ frameworks/runtime-src/Classes`
  `cp -R tools/bindings-generator/test/simple_test_bindings/ frameworks/runtime-src/Classes`
- Update `CMakeLists.txt` and `frameworks/runtime-src/proj.android/jni/Android.mk` and add the added files `autogentestbindings.cpp` and `simple_class.cpp` to the target lists.
- Register the jsb functions in the runtime sources in `frameworks/runtime-src/Classes/AppDelegate.cpp` by adding `sc->addRegisterCallback(register_all_autogentestbindings);` in `AppDelegate::applicationDidFinishLaunching`

Then classes defined in `simple_class.h` are available in Javascript. The following JS code should display `1337`.

`console.log((new SimpleNativeClass(1337)).getSomeField())`